# Why in particle physics the background of resonance is a decaying exponential?

Tags: particle-physics, resonance, large-hadron-collider

When in particle physics they plot the mass histogram we see a resonance on top of a decaying exponential background?

Why is the background modeled to be that way? what is the physical explanation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Decaying exponentials are the result of there being a fixed probability of any specific member of a population being removed.  Once removed, the population decreases and so the rate of decay also decreases.  The rate of decay is therefore associated with a particular time scale related to the change in population.  The same model works if the population is growing - it still leads to an exponential, just one that's growing.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question. OP is asking about the shape of combinatoric background in invariant mass spectra.